# Stack Complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack, time-complexity, big-o

How to calculate the Complexity of the Stack?
Yes, I mean the various operations of Stack (Push, Pop). How it can be said that the complexity for these operations will be O(1).

Comment: There is no such thing as "complexity of a stack". Perhaps you mean the complexity of the various operations (like push, pop)?

Comment: What do you mean by "How to calculate"? Do you actually want to know the how the algorithmic complexity of stack operations is derived, or do you just want to know the answers?

Comment: I'm tempted to invoke *"No question too basic"* on this, but I'm not sure what good it would do to reopen it: the OP seems to be either unclear on how complexity analysis is done or unclear on what kinds of implementations are used for stacks. I mean, I *can* write a stack that is O(n) for push and pop, it would just be really silly. @Temp: Can you clarify what you *do* understand about the problem?

Answer (score 8):

- **Pop** `Θ(1)`
- **Push** `Θ(1)`

Because this operations not depends on size of stack and not depends on nothing.

Comment: Yes, I mean the various operations of Stack (Push, Pop). How it can be said that the complexity for these operations will be O(1).

Comment: @0xA3: stack is not a interface is a algorithm and in not invalid implementation all operations on her is in constant time not depending on number of elements.